# CRUD EN UN SEGUNDO FORMULARIO JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo un CRUD de varias tablas, entre ellas participantes que esta en el `JFrame` principal, y ya el segundo CRUD canciones esta en otro `JFrame` almacenado en un `MenuBar` dentro de un `MenuItem`. que al presionar se desplega. solo que al este desplegarse ya no hace ninguna accion.

esta es la pantalla principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego en la opción tablas se despliegue la opción de baile y aparece lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en esta ya no muestra nada, el método de mostrar los datos ya esta implementado, de igual forma con el botón nuevo puse un JOPTIONPANE pero tampoco lo muestra...

en el código de la interfaz principal tengo este código para que se visualice todo:

```
vista v=new vista();
           Controlador con=new Controlador(v);
           v.setVisible(true);
           v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

y en el método de baile este...

```
bailevista b=new bailevista();
           controladorb co=new controladorb(b);
           v.setVisible(true);
           v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

y en el menú para desplegar el `JFrame` principal en el menú para que despliegue el otro  es el siguiente:

```
private void baileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        bailevista b = new bailevista();
        b.setVisible(true);
        //this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

no se si me puedan ayudar para que a la hora de abrir el segundo `JFrame` este ejecute las funciones del CRUD

Comment: en tu código le falta la parte donde le pasa los datos de una ventana a otra, puede ser en el constructor o mediante setter, no te podemos ayudar más sin más código

Comment: Hola. No estoy pasando ningún dato. Son tablas independientes entre sí. La indo la traigo desde una base de datos y utilizo MVC. En el primer jframe si funciona pero al abrir el otro que esta en el menú. Ya no s muestra nada

Comment: justo ese es el problema, sin datos no pintará nada. Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171331/pasar-informacion-de-un-jtable-que-esta-en-un-jframe-a-otro-jframe